# Proving $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}+\frac{3n\sqrt[3]{abc}}{a+b+c}\geq n+3$ for $n\leq 3$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

A math olympiad inequality:

> How can prove that
> $$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}+\frac{3n\sqrt[3]{abc}}{a+b+c}\geq n+3$$ with $n\leq3$

I know that
$$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}\geq \frac{a+b+c}{\sqrt[3]{abc}}$$ but if I apply am-gm at the end I get that
$$2\sqrt[2]{3n}\geq3+n$$ but that's only true for $n = 3$. so surely there is another way to go.

Thanks

Comment: Check your problem statement. If $a=b=c=1$ what happens, irrespective of whatever $n$ is.

Comment: OP - I fixed the problem. Try it now.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost , the bound you get is loose because you did not satisfy the condition of equality in AM-GM $(\frac{a+b+c}{\sqrt[3]{abc}} \neq \frac{3n\sqrt[3]{abc}}{a+b+c})$ so the minimum is never attained.

**Answer:**

First of all , we will need to prove the following lemma

**Lemma  :**

$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{b} \geq \frac{a+b+c}{\sqrt[3]{abc}}$$

**Proof:**

By AM-GM:
$$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c} \geq 3\sqrt[3]{\frac{a^2}{bc}}=3\sqrt[3]{\frac{a^3}{abc}}=3\frac{a}{\sqrt[3]{abc}}$$

Adding the sum cyclically will yield the wanted result with equality when $a=b=c$

Now what is left to proof is:

$$\frac{a+b+c}{\sqrt[3]{abc}} + \frac{3n\sqrt[3]{abc}}{a+b+c} \geq 3+n$$

**Proof:**

First , we put $z=\frac{a+b+c}{\sqrt[3]{abc}}$

Then the inequality turns into :
$$z+\frac{3n}{z} \geq 3+n$$

Now we can see that the condition of equality does not hold , so How do we fix this problem ?

Well we can for a couple $(\frac{z}{\alpha},\frac{3n}{z})$ s.t the two terms are equal:

Then it is equivalent to solving (for $\alpha$):

$$\frac{z}{\alpha}=\frac{3n}{z}$$ $\Longleftrightarrow$
$$\alpha =\frac{z^2}{3n}$$

Knowing that we need to minimize $\alpha$ , therefore minimizing $\frac{z^2}{3n} $ which means minimizing $z$

we can subtitute the min value of $z$ which is  3 (since $a+b+c \geq 3\sqrt[3]{abc}$)  and so :

$$\alpha=\frac{3}{n}$$

Then we can re-write our z term as:
$$z=\frac{zn}{3}+\frac{3z-zn}{3}$$

Hence :
$$\frac{zn}{3}+\frac{3n}{z} \geq 2n$$
and since $z\geq3$
$$\frac{3z-zn}{3}=\frac{z(3-n)}{3} \geq 3-n$$

and thus

$$z+\frac{3n}{z} \geq 2n+3-n=n+3$$

with equality when $a=b=c$

Q.E.D

Comment: if  we didn't have the coniditon $n\leq 3$  then $n-3 \leq 0$ and so we wouldn't  have been able to sum the two inequalities , that is why it plays a big role in this problem